# What is this class(type) called in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

```
class X
{

    void method1(){}

    void method2(){}

}
class Y
{

     void someMethod()
     {

            /* 
               What is this type below called?
               Anonymous class or 
               Anonymous-Inherited class or what??? 
            */
            X xInstance = new X(){

               @Override
               void method1()
               {
                    System.out.println("What kinda class is this ?");
               }   
            }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an anonymous inner (or nested) class.

Reference: [Local and Anonymous Inner Classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)

Comment: Are you saying it is not inheriting anything from Class X ? . I see that i have access to super(is that correct?). What is actually happening in relation to Object hierarchy ? How does it work ? It looks like a anonymous child of Class X. Am I right ?

Comment: @panzerschreck: It's inheriting X, but it's still an anonymous class because it has no name. Yes, you can access the parent class (super). The hierarchy is `Object -> X -> YourAnonymous`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 X xInstance = new X(){

               @Override
               void method1()
               {
                    System.out.println("What kinda class is this ?");
               }   
            }
     }
```

It is [anonymous](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) class. you have overriden implementation of `method1()`